# 2D Colliders are Inconsistent in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision

I'm making a game in Unity with C#, and right now I'm working on a turret that can shoot projectiles at the player. They work fine, always going towards the player, but sometimes they don't collide with the player. They go straight through them and into the ground, which they do collide with. Both the player and the projectiles' Rigidbody2Ds are set to continuous, so I have no clue what's happening. After some basic testing, the diagram below shows what I've found out about this collision bug. Sorry for the sloppiness, it's just a quick mock-up.

[image: Diagram]

The purple point is the turret itself and where the projectiles are being fired from, the green is where the player is almost always safe, the yellow is where the player is sometimes safe (it seems incredibly inconsistent, so it's only an approximation), and the red is where the projectiles almost always collide with the player. I want the player to always collide with the projectile, no matter where they are.

I would add my code, but it's pretty basic. I'm using C#, like I said before, and I just use OnTriggerEnter2D to find the collisions. The player uses a box collider which does not have "is trigger" enabled, while the projectile uses a box collider which does. Sorry if this problem is really weird. If you need any more info, feel free to ask.

The projectiles are instantiated at the turret, and their velocity is calculated with

```
Vector2 dir = playerRB.position - projectileRB.position;
    angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x);
    xVel = projectileSpeed * Mathf.Cos(angle);
    yVel = projectileSpeed * Mathf.Sin(angle);
    projectileRB.velocity = new Vector2(xVel, yVel);
```

Comment: Please add your code in particular for firing and moving the projectiles and Inspector settings for player and bullet prefab

Comment: Okay, I added some code if it helps

Answer (score 0):

If things are moving too fast the colliders will not detect a hit.

You said you use `OnTriggerEnter2D`, to trigger a collision that calls this function the colliders of the projectile and the player must overlap in one of the FixedUpdate calls.

If the projectile is moving too fast, then it will pass trough the player without ever overlaping, because at 1 'frame' it's behind the player, and in the next one it passed it.
and this is what causes the inconsistency.

You can theoretically solve it by increacing the physics calculations per second, but this won't be the right thing for your case.

because projectiles move fast and move in a stright line, what you should do is check with a [raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html) if the player is infront of the projectile and use it to check if the projectile is hitting the player, if the ray collided with the player, register a hit, make sure you don't a ray that is too long, because this will give you false positives, but also make sure that even if the player is having low frame rate, then the detection is still 100% consistent

If you want to make the game more fair, then you can add another raycast behind the projectile, and only trigger the hit if both rays detected a hit with the player's collider.

The direction of the ray should be the same direction the projectile is facing, the the rear ray should be the opposite direction.

to get the direction you can use TransformDirection for the direction of the raycast, assuming the projectile is facing the same direction it is going.

I need to assume and cannot provide a code, since you havn't provided any code, therefore I can't tell what exactly you are using to move the projectile and how it behaves

Comment: I just set the velocity of the projectile (I added my code to the question) with projectileRB.velocity = new Vector2. I tried raycasting forwards and backwards like you said, but it doesn't seem to work, probably because the player is small and it doesn't cast frequently enough. For example, the forwards raycast and the backwards raycast are the same when going through a thick wall, but not a thin floor. The code is making two new raycasts every update, checking if they hit anything, then checking if the transform.name of both of them is the player.

Comment: Afaik that's not entirely true. If using Rigidbody Unity also calculates the in-between steps and the collision should get triggered also if an object would pass a collider between two physics updates

Comment: Well my code is RaycastHit2D hitInfoForward = Physics2D.Raycast(projectileRB.position, new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(angle), Mathf.Sin(angle)));
        RaycastHit2D hitInfoBackward = Physics2D.Raycast(projectileRB.position, new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(angle2), Mathf.Sin(angle2)));
        if (hitInfoForward && hitInfoBackward) {
            Debug.Log("both hitInfos exist, checking for player");
            if (hitInfoForward.transform.name == "player" && hitInfoBackward.transform.name == "player") {
                   player.GameOver();

            }
        } Am I doing it wrong?